# How do I count the frequency of a specific word within each cell?

Tags: python, pandas

Here is my Pandas dataframe -

```
# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd

# initialize list elements
data = {'Company': ['Nike', 'Levi', 'Dell'],
        'Items': ['Running Shoes, Walking Shoes, Socks', 'Jeans, Jackets, Designer Shoes', 'Laptops'],
        'Specified_Word':['Shoes', 'Shoes', 'Laptops']}

# Create the pandas DataFrame with column name is provided explicitly
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df['count'] = [2,1,1]
print(df.head())
```

I am basically trying to count the frequency of the word `Shoes` in the first 2 rows of the column `Items`. However, for the last row of that column I'd like to count the frequency of the word `Laptops`. These number need to be placed in the column `count`. Basically,  I need to count the frequency of the word in the column `Specified_Word` within the corresponding cell in `Items`. I would like to automate the generation of the column `count`. As of now, it is apparent that it's manually generated.

I cannot use `str.count()` because it counts across the entire column. I need to perform the counting per cell.

The big picture here is that I am trying to compute the term frequency of certain words using Pandas. Term frequency is typically computed for documents, but over here they are cells of the column `Items`.

Comment: `.str.count` does count per cell: `df['Items'].str.count('Shoes|Laptops')` gives the expected output.

Comment: If you had `Laptops` in the first row, would you want to count it together with `Shoes`?

Comment: @mozway @Quang Hoang - I apologize for the confusion. Basically I want to know a way to count the occurences of a word within a pandas cell. The reason I used the example `Shoes` and `Laptops` was to give a minimal working example. Please let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: @QuangHoang I don't want it to count the occurrence of a word that I did not specify.

Comment: define *specify*? Is it a different word for different cells? how do you specify that *automatically*?

Comment: I have updated the question with the column 'Specified_Word'. I need to count the frequency of the word in the column `Specified_Word` within the corresponding cell in `Items`. Thank you for this comment. My question was quite unclear without it.

Comment: OK, makes more sense.

Comment: I can't understand how the desired result should be `[2,1,0]` and not `[2,1,1]`.  Can you please explain the last value?

Comment: Thank you for catching it. I have made it `[2,1,1]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to loop:

```
df['count'] = [s.count(w) for w, s in zip(df['Specified_Word'], df['Items'])]
```

Output:

```
  Company                                Items Specified_Word  count
0    Nike  Running Shoes, Walking Shoes, Socks          Shoes      2
1    Levi       Jeans, Jackets, Designer Shoes          Shoes      1
2    Dell                              Laptops        Laptops      1
```

Answer (score 2):

For updated data you can use `apply`:

```
df['count'] = df.apply(lambda r: str(r['Items']).count(str(r['Specified_Word'])), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def function1(ss:pd.Series):
        ss['count']=ss.Items.count(ss.Specified_Word)
        return ss

df.apply(function1,axis=1)
```

Output:

```
 Company                                Items Specified_Word  count
0    Nike  Running Shoes, Walking Shoes, Socks          Shoes      2
1    Levi       Jeans, Jackets, Designer Shoes          Shoes      1
2    Dell                              Laptops        Laptops      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
df['count'] = [x['Items'].count(x['Specified_Word']) for i, x in df.iterrows()]
```